# Fix or hide 'styleimagemissing' console warning from Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

After changing one of the data sources for a Mapbox component, I get these `styleimagemissing` console warnings alerting that some icons for points of interest are not available. For my purposes it's OK that those icons aren't shown, so I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid getting these warnings from the frontend code, without changing the data sources. Perhaps ignoring points of interest or images/icons?

I've already tried writing some function that's triggered when an image is missing instead of the warning:

```
map.on('styleimagemissing', () => {
// do something
});
```

But this seems to happen after the warning has already been triggered.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could simply load a transparent icon for every icon that is in the style (assuming you can determine such a list).

Comment: Thanks Steve, will try that ASAP. In case I can't get a fix in there before my team has to push to production, do you happen to know if these could cause some sort of crash at some point? Of course we don't want lingering warnings in general but it'd be useful to know if we have some leeway.

Comment: I don't think there are any other effects other than warning messages.